# android animate property

Tags: android, animation, properties

is there any way to apply an animation to a property of a view? currently, the only animation i am aware of is applying an animation to an entire view.  i'm wondering if i can apply an animation to a property (i.e. layout_width for example)

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the animation to affect only certain parts of the view.  For example, I wanted a `ViewFlipper` to look like it was flipping over vertically, so I made the out animation shrink the y of the view to 0 in the middle and the in animation grow the y from the middle.  Here's what they look like.

**shrink_to_middle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="50%"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

**grow_from_middle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200" />
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%"
        android:toYDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="200"/>
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to apply the animation only to a property of the view you still have to set it as the view's animation.

```
<scale 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0" 
    android:toXScale="0" />
```

This animation for example changes the width of your view.

You can set the Animation by

```
yourView.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation_name));
```

Comment: yes, but the problem is that this scales the entire view.  so if the view has a background with a 1 dip border (for example) then the border gets thicker as the animation plays.  i want to apply the animation to the property and then have the xml drawable re-draw so that the border stays at 1 dip.

Comment: You can use a 9-Patch as a drawable for the background and define the border as a non-stretching area, so your border stays at a fixed with.

Comment: I like that idea... but... now the question becomes, is there a way to create a 9patch via xml drawable... :)